# How to correctly line break and concatenate a string in a bash script

Tags: bash, string, echo

I have a Bash script with a function to log messages with time and status, and I want to keep my script 80 column only:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

log_message() {
  echo "[$(date)]-[$1] : $2" >> log.txt
}

varName="John Doe"

# line break to not exceed 80 columns
log_message "WARNING" "I am "${varName}" and i want to limit this line \
to 80 columns"
```

The result in log file is not as expected:

```
[Fri Jun 24 13:50:12 CEST 2022]-[WARNING] : I am John
```

What is the correct way of doing this in Bash?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: If you found any of the answers useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) one of them so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI, a better `log_message` in `bash` could be written:

```
exec {logfd}>> log.txt
log_message() {
  local severity="$1" message
  shift
  for message do
    printf '[%(%FT%T%z)T]-[%s] : %s\n' -1 "$severity" "$message" >&"$logfd"
  done
}
```

Which avoids running one `date` command and reopening the log file each time, and lets you pass more than one message (each message displayed on a separate line).

Then use `\` for line continuation as already mentioned by @AdminBee. Note that in sh/bash, as opposed to most other languages, it's around parameter expansions or characters that are special to the shell that you need to but the quotes. With `"...."${var}"..."` you ended up leaving the `${var}` unquoted which meant it undergoes split+glob!

```
log_message WARNIN\
G "I am ${varName}\
 and I want to lim\
it this line to 20\
 columns"
```

Is an option. Beware line continuations like that (with `\` followed by newline), works inside or outside double quotes, or in here documents, but not inside single quotes nor here-documents with a quoted delimiter.

With that `log_message`, you could also do:

```
log_message WARNING \
  "I am ${varName}" \
  'and I want to limit' \
  'the length of the lines' \
  'in the log file.'
```

To get in `log.txt`:

```
[2022-06-24T13:28:46+0100]-[WARNING] : I am John Doe
[2022-06-24T13:28:46+0100]-[WARNING] : and I want to limit
[2022-06-24T13:28:46+0100]-[WARNING] : the length of the lines
[2022-06-24T13:28:46+0100]-[WARNING] : in the log file.
```

Answer (score 5):

In your case, the problem is not the line continuation, but the fact that you used double-quotes inside your double-quoted second argument without escaping them (*Note that seeing the answer by @Stéphane, it may be that you actually intended this - see below for why this is not a good idea*). Try it with

```
log_message "WARNING" "I am \"${varName}\" and i want to limit this line \
to 80 columns"
```

With your unescaped quotes before `${varName}`, the variable reference is now actually [*outside* the double-quotes and subject to word-splitting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/377345), so the `log_message` call sees the following arguments:

- `WARNING`
- `I am John` (the `John` part will still be considered part of the second token because it follows the "closing" double-quote immediately)
- `Doe and i want to limit this line to 80 columns` (`Doe` is attached to the third argument for the same reason as `John` is part of the second)

However, your function `log_message` only interprets the first two arguments, so the remaining string fragment is lost.